# What is the best practice for encapsulation with Entity Framework and Code First strategy?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

What is the best practice respecting the encapsulation?

I am using code first strategy with Entity Framework in .NET 6.

```
public class Employee
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public void SetName(string value)
    {
        this.Name = value;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Employee
{
    private string _name;        

    [Required]
    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; } 
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Employee
{
   [Required]
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried out all three options? Do any not work, or have limitations? What objective measurement are you looking for with a "best practice"?

Comment: The three options works. I dont know if someone have limitations. Im looking the best practice using the GRASP patterns with encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely personal preference and working through the scenarios you expect to encounter and how you want to safeguard or streamline them.

As a general rule I personally advocate for simplicity. A simple domain that is easy to understand is easy for other developers and consumers to pick up or otherwise be instructed. Often these decisions are made to try and restrict developers so-as to silo the domain so that UI developers for example either cannot directly modify data, or try and tightly control access. This may be necessary in very large projects/teams and can work provided your "gate keepers" can keep updates regular and consistent so that everyone can do what needs to be done, but often due to time constraints or responsibilities changing hands (gatekeepers leave and get backfilled by others that don't understand or agree) then bypasses inevitably leak into the model just leading to a confusing and unnecessarily complicated mess.

When it comes to the domain, I generally follow a more DDD-based approach similar to your first example, except I only use methods where I expect that there is a validation or specific combination of state that the entity can enforce itself. The responsibility for mutator methods like this either fall on the entity or the repository. (As I typically use a repository pattern)

For a value that can just change and might have simple validation or none at all, I will just use public setters. For no validation:

```
 public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

for basic validation that the entity can validate itself, using either attributes or validation logic inside the setter:

```
private string _someValue;
public string SomeValue
{
   get { return _someValue; }
   set 
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new ArgumentException("SomeValue is not optional."); 
       _someValue = value;
   }
}
```

Often, Updates to state involve changing more than one thing where the combination of data should be validated together against the current remainder of the entity state. We don't want to set values one at a time because this means that the entity state could be left in an invalid state, or there is no guarantee that a caller will not simply set one value, ignoring the fact that the other values are technically invalid.  As a very rough example of the concept, without getting into validation, it would be updating an address. Sure, it is possible that we may want to make a correction to a single address field, but typically if we are changing one address field we will most likely be invalidating the rest. For example, if I have an address that contains a Street Name, Number, City, PostCode, and Country, changing just the city or just the country would most often make the address completely invalid. In these cases I would use a Setter method to encapsulate updating an address:

```
public string Country { get; internal set; }
public string City { get; internal set; }
public string PostCode { get; internal set; }
public string StreetName { get; internal set; }
public string StreetNumber { get; set; }

public void UpdateAddress(string country, string city, string postCode, string streetName, string streetNumber)
{ // ...
}
```

It might be fine to allow them to just change the street number on it's own, or possibly even the street name without calling UpdateAddress so these might have public setters. City and Country might be FK values (CityId/CountryId) so there would be even less need to update these independenty. Simply having this method gate-keep the setting of the value should send a clear message to developers that they should be ensuring the complete and valid address details are sent at once, not relying on them correctly chaining piecemeal updates.

Where I might want to validate changes against existing data state, I would use an Internal setter, and have the update method as part of the Repository. For example if I want to allow them to update a Name, but ensure the name is unique. The repository has access to the domain, so I find it's a good location for this responsibility:

```
public void UpdateUserName(User user, string newName)
{
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("newName");
    if (user.Name == newName) return; // Nothing to do.

    var nameExists = _context.Users.Any(x => x.Name == newName && x.UserId != user.UserId);
    if (nameExists) throw new ArgumentException("The name is not unique.");
    user.Name = newName; // Allowed via the internal Setter.
}
```

It would be expected that if this was talking to a UI that the UI would validate that the name was unique prior to saving, but persistence should validate in case this can be called by other avenues like APIs, where things like unique constraints on the DB serve as the final guard.

Similarly, when it comes to creating entities, I will use factory methods much like the above in the Repository classes to do things like CreateAddress(...) which ensure that address entities are not simply newed up and filled adhoc. This ensures that when an entity is created, all required fields & relationships are provided and filled. The objective of this approach is to help ensure that from the point an entity is created and at every point through its mutation it is in a valid and complete state.

Hopefully that gives you some food for thought on the subject. Ultimately though you should look at what is important for your particular scenario and what real and actual problems you want to address. Don't get too caught up on trying to ward off hypothetical worst-case scenarios and ending up with something so rigid that it negatively impacts your coding responsiveness.